# how to have a reference to child generic type from a parent generic type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

here is the scenario

```
class MyClass1{

}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass1{

}

class Parent<T>{
 List<T> list;
}


class Child extends Parent<MyClass2>{
}
```

this doesn't compile

```
Parent<MyClass1> p = new Child();
```

this does

```
Parent<MyClass2> p = new Child();
```

why?

is there a way to refer via parent type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
Parent<MyClass1> p = new Child();
```

doesn't compile, because the `Child` class has defined the type parameter `T` to be `MyClass2`.  All `Child` objects are `Parent<MyClass2>` objects, and a `Parent<MyClass2>` is not a `Parent<MyClass1>`, even if a `MyClass2` is a `MyClass1`.  That's because Java's generics are invariant.

The solution to get this to compile when using `MyClass1` is to use a bounded wildcard.

```
Parent<? extends MyClass1> p = new Child();
```

The wildcard allows the relationship between `MyClass2` and `MyClass1` to extend to `Parent<MyClass2>` and `Parent<? extends MyClass1>`.

Answer (score 4):

[This is how generics works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html). You've explicitly stated that class `Child` is a subclass of `Parent<MyClass2>`. But `Parent<MyClass2>` is not a subclass of `Parent<MyClass1>`, so therefore Child is not a subclass of `Parent<MyClass1>`.

Change your constructor call to

```
Parent<? extends MyClass1> p = new Child();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is a concept called **covariance**. In your implementation the fact that `MyClass1 extends MyClass2` does not mean that `Parent<MyClass1> extends Parent<MyClass2>` so `Parent<MyClass1> p = new Child();` does not compile.

You have to explicitly mention this in your instantiation:

```
Parent<? extends MyClass1> p = new Child();
```

So now you tell compiler that `T` is subclass of `MyClass1` so compiler let it go.

Answer (score 1):

With your `Child` class definition, you're stating that the only type of Generic `Parent` will accept is `MyClass2`. If you want **both** `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` to be accepted as Generics in `Parent`, do this:

```
class MyClass1{}
class MyClass2 extends MyClass1{}
class Parent<T extends MyClass1>
{ List<T> list; }
class Child<T extends MyClass1> extends Parent<T>{}
```